# Pick multiple images from gallery and display in the viewpager

Tags: java, android

I have an app where I need to pick multiple images from gallery and display them in viewpager. I did only picking one image and display it in image view like this:

```
private void chooseImage() {
        Intent openGalleryIntent = new Intent();
        openGalleryIntent.setType("image/*");
        openGalleryIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        openGalleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(openGalleryIntent, "Select Picture"), GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();

            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                if (photoMekanik) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    photoMekanik = false;
                } else if (photoElektonik) {
                    imageView2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    photoElektonik = false;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [ImagePicker](https://github.com/esafirm/android-image-picker) library to do that easily

to pick multiple images just do this

```
ImagePicker.create(this)
.multi() // multi mode (default mode)
.start(); // start image picker activity with request code
```

**Receive result**

inside `onActivityResult()` do this

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, final int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (ImagePicker.shouldHandle(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        // Get a list of picked images
        List<Image> images = ImagePicker.getImages(data)
        // or get a single image only
        Image image = ImagePicker.getFirstImageOrNull(data)
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: cannot install it

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of this lib from github to done your work :

https://github.com/search?l=Java&q=multiple+image+picker&type=Repositories